# partial string matching in R? Is this possible?

Tags: regex, string, match, partial

I'm not actually sure if this is possible. I have these two data frames that have scientific names. Some of them are misspelled, some have missing spaces, others are homonyms (not the same species), and others match. So I have something like this:

```
stringDF <- data.frame(string = c("Abietinella abietina (Hedw.) M.Fleisch.", "Abietinella abietina (Hedw.) M. Fleisch.", "Abietinella abietina (Hedw.) Smith", "Abitinella abietina (Hedw.) M. Fleisch."))
patternDF <- data.frame(string = "Abietinella abietina (Hedw.) M. Fleisch.", match = "A")
```

patternDF has the "correct name" plus a column (that I'm calling "match" containing important information. I'm trying to make a "match" column in stringDF where "A" is pasted when it matches partially. So ideally, I'd like something like this:

```
string                                      match
Abietinella abietina (Hedw.) M.Fleisch.     A
Abietinella abietina (Hedw.) M. Fleisch.    A
Abietinella abietina (Hedw.) Smith          NA
Abitinella abietina (Hedw.) M. Fleisch.     A
```

I've tried using this function:

```
stringDF$match <- patternDF$match[pmatch(stringDF$string, patternDF$string)]
```

but I'm not having any luck. Is this possible to do in R? I've also tried using the %like% function from the data.frame package.

I'm not the best at coding, so sorry in advance for my ignorance! Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `stringdist` library ([cran here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html)) to accomplish this without some hack-around solution with regex. Regex fuzzy matches are available in some packages and other languages (like [PyPi regex for Python](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) - *see Approximate "fuzzy" matching*).

In any case, it's likely better to use a Levenshtein distance functions for your case (google it for more information - [this link](https://dzone.com/articles/the-levenshtein-algorithm-1) has decent information on it).

```
library(stringdist)

stringdist("Abietinella abietina (Hedw.) M. Fleisch.",c("Abietinella abietina (Hedw.) M.Fleisch.", "Abietinella abietina (Hedw.) M. Fleisch.", "Abietinella abietina (Hedw.) Smith", "Abitinella abietina (Hedw.) M. Fleisch."))
```

Running the code above yields the following:

```
1 0 9 1
```

Those are the Levenshtein distances for each of the 4 strings respectively. You can use the result with some coding logic to only accept those with low enough Levenshtein values. Based on your current strings, I might suggest only keeping strings with values `<=4`, but you can tweak it as needed.

Comment: This is great! I used a nested for loop using the stringdist() function to get the output I needed. Thank you so much!